# How to remove the delete option form activeAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin

in rails gem active admin I want to remove the delete option form the default_actions while I still need the edit and show action , is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You add a call to `actions` to every Active Admin resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Foobar do
  actions :all, :except => [:destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 10):

At some point I had this problem, because of the destroy method, the 'Delete' button didn't disappear

```
actions :all, except: [:destroy]

controller do
  def destroy # => Because of this the 'Delete' button was still there
    @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    super
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer threw an exception, "wrong number of arguments" so I did this to exclude the delete button(:destroy action)

```
ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  actions :index, :show, :new, :create, :update, :edit

   index do

     selectable_column
     id_column
     column :title
     column :email
     column :name

    actions 
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to remove actions from default_actions for an `ActiveAdmin` resource is via `config` variable, like:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register MyUser do
      config.remove_action_item(:destroy)
      ...
    end
```

> One way is already mentioned in the accepted answer via `actions` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the remove the destroy button completely use:

```rb
actions :all, except: [:destroy]
```

But if the delete button needs condition based on the resource properties.(e.g. associated data or status).

At index page:

```rb
index do

  # ...

  actions defaults: false do |row|
    if can? :read, row
      text_node link_to "View", admin_resource_path(row), class: "view_link"
    end
    if can? :edit, row
      text_node link_to "Edit", admin_resource_path(row), class: "edit_link"
    end
    if can? :destroy, row
      text_node link_to I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), admin_resource_path(row), method: :delete, data: { confirm: I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation') }, class: "delete_link" if row.deletable?
    end
  end
end
```

Now the complex part and i had to bang my head several times to control it at show page:

```rb
config.remove_action_item(:destroy) # will remove the destroy button
  
action_item only: :show  do
  link_to I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), admin_resource_path(resource), method: :delete, data: { confirm: I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation') }, class: "delete_link" if resource.deletable?
end
```

Sorry for my terrible formatting.